# Plugin alternative to Normalize.CSS?

Tags: plugins

Hello Wordpress world!

Since Normalize.CSS is not actually a wordpress plugin, could someone recommend me something close to it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this maybe close to what you need http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-bootstrap-css/